# Time increments in events only increasing by 15 minutes. Can't be specific

Tags: civievent, drupal, webform-civicrm

I was wondering if we could set time to be 11:50 instead of always being reverted back to 11:45.

[image: screenshot of event date fields on a Drupal webform]

Comment: Can you add more details - civi version, which screen is this, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That’s a Drupal screen -> you need to go to Manage Fields (for the Content Type that this field is on) and hit Edit -> change its configuration